# Unable to read HTML data correctly in Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'm trying to read HTML data of the following page in Python 3:

```
http://dl.nlai.ir/UI/25d36bb4-72aa-43c1-af2d-086540db8aea/LRRView.aspx
```

and I'm doing it in this way:

```
url=str(input('\n Paste URL here: '))    
url2=requests.get(url)
html=url2.text
print(html)
```

but it returns contents of an error page.

Let me add that you may encounter the same error page in web browser, but to avoid that, opening this address at first will solve it:

```
http://dl.nlai.ir/ui/forms/Index.aspx
```

What's your recommendation to read data correctly?, I want to get content of the page to extract a base64-encoded string from source page.

Comment: You may have an error involving cookies. Try having a request to the `Index.aspx` page, parse the cookies received in the header, and then passing them with your request using `cookies=my_cookies)`

Comment: I'm a beginner with Python, I don't know how to set cookies. Could you please elaborate more? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

unless you visit the "http://dl.nlai.ir/ui/forms/Index.aspx" first, 
visit "http://dl.nlai.ir/UI/25d36bb4-72aa-43c1-af2d-086540db8aea/LRRView.aspx" will get wrong html. So I guess you need session get the url, like this

```
s = requests.Session()
url1 = 'http://dl.nlai.ir/ui/forms/Index.aspx'
url = 'http://dl.nlai.ir/UI/25d36bb4-72aa-43c1-af2d-086540db8aea/LRRView.aspx'
s.get(url1)
url2 = s.get(url)
html = url2.text
print(html)
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Although I had to set header as well, since it was showing an error regarding "not supported browser".

Comment: after trying few times, it seems they restricted access for [either my IP, or session, etc] and it shows a page that "You don't have access to view this area", is it possible to bypass this limitation also?

Comment: try this:  add header info and use proxy ip.  your IP may be banned by the site.